# Adding quotation marks to elements in a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Suppose we have a list of lists with 5 lists:

```
master_list = [list1, list2, list3, list4, list5]
```

I want to get the column names to be:

```
cols = ["list1", "list2", "list3", "list4", "list5"]
```

How could I extract these names from `master_list`?

**Edit**. I guess you  can manually add quotations to the elements of `cols` list and then if you wanted to create a dataframe, do something like:

```
import pandas as pd
df_output = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(list1, list2, list3, list4, list5 )),
                   columns =cols)
```

Comment: You can't.  The lists as stored in `master_list` do not have names.  They happen to be bound to the same list objects.  You should store the lists in a dictionary to begin with.  That makes them easier to handle, and makes extracting the keys trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an important point.  Consider the following snippet:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a
c = b
d = c
```

After that, how many list objects are there?  The answer is 1.  There is exactly one list.  It happens to be bound to four different local names.  (This is why doing `b[1] = 9` is seen in all four names.)

The list object itself does not know any of the names to which it is bound.  The list is anonymous.  If you need things to be named, you use a dictionary.

```
master_list = {
    'list1': list1,
    'list2': list2,
    'list3': list3,
    'list4': list4
}

cols = list(master_list.keys())
```

Comment: I guess you could manually add quotations to the elements in cols and then if you want to create a dataframe, do something like: df_output = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(list1, list2, list3, list4, list5 )),
               columns =cols)

Comment: Yep.  Partly, it depends on what makes sense for you and how large your data set is.

Answer (score 0):

If the column names are the first values of each list then you can do this:

```py
master_list = [
    ['test1', 1, 2, 3],
    ['test2', 1, 2, 3],
    ['test3', 1, 2, 3],
    ['test4', 1, 2, 3],
    ['test5', 1, 2, 3],
]
column_names = list(zip(*master_list))[0]
```

If you just want to create column names then this could work:

```py
column_names = [f'list{i}' for i in range(len(master_list))]
```